# Offline Registration Form

Tags: offline, offline-mode

I need to create an offline registration form. I want to use these forms in different computers without any internet support. The form also needs to store data. I was thinking of installing xampp(localhost) on all the computers but it would be troublesome if any problem occurs.
Please help.

Comment: What is supposed to happen to the data entered into the forms?

Comment: We need to save that data.

Comment: Save where? How do you propose to access it later?

Comment: Save it in database or any doc if possible.

Answer (score 0):

An Adobe PDF is a decent offline form. It really depends on what needs to happen to the information once the form has been completed.